# Unable to upload otf files using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, fonts, upload

I was trying to upload font files in wordpress upload using `wp_handle_upload()`

To allow the types of  font files ,i added the bellow code in my functions.php

```
  function allow_font_mime_types($mimes) {
  $mimes['eot']   = 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject';
  $mimes['woff']  = 'application/font-woff'; 
  $mimes['otf']   = 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template';
  $mimes['svg']   = 'image/svg+xml';

  return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'allow_font_mime_types');
```

all files except otf was uploaded.but when we try to uload otf ,it throws an error

> this file type is not permitted for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

I think it may help you

```
$mimes['otf'] = 'application/font-sfnt';
```

Or Use this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/use-any-font/

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your configure.php file. Add this little code on it

```
define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
```

To understand it properly follow this [link](https://niamrox.com/how-to-fix-sorry-this-file-type-is-not-permitted-for-security-reasons-error-in-wordpress/)